# Equalize two linear systems to find common vector lying in both column spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Lets assume I have two matrices which span subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$. How can I find out if there is a vector lying in both of them?

This is how far I've got:

I think I have to equalize both systems:

$Ax_1 = Bx_2$

The book I am learning from gives me the hint to think of a matrix [A B]. But how can I get from $Ax_1 = Bx_2$ to something like $[A ~ B] [x_1 ~ x_2]^T = 0$?

My idea is to reduce then $[A ~ B]$ to the reduced row echelon form and find a special solution in its nullspace. This special soultion can then be split up into $x_1$ and $x_2$ to find a vector which lies in both vector spaces.

Comment: Try to find maximal linearly indepemdent group in both systems and  pick up "same" vectors from both systems.("same" means two vectors are independent)

Comment: What does it mean for a matrix to span a subspace?

Comment: I mean that the colomns of a matrix span a vector space. Like the identity matrix spans the whole R^3. In my case the columns only span a subspace because m > n

Comment: I would first reduce $A$ and $B$ so that their columns are linearly independent, to get $A'$ and $B'$, say. Then put them side by side to form $M = [A' B']$. Then do row reduction on $M$. If you lose a row, then you know there is a common vector. Otherwise, there are none and $A$ and $B$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Triviality alert: of course there is always a vector lying in both subspaces, namely, the zero vector. If you want to know whether there is a nonzero vector lying in both subspaces, I endorse the comment by @Colm.